# set html img src from byte array

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications

I am working on an email client application in C#.

I want to display an html email on the page with embedded images.
Now, I use a div and set mail bodyhtml to div innerhtml property. 
I have a problem with display embedded images.

I know everything about embedded images (content-type, name, content-id, base64string or byte[] as content)

I used image data uri, but unfortunately it is not too perfect, for example (ie8-32KB limitation).

I tried to ihttphandler as imagehandler, but it is not run on a simple postback, when I set div inner html.

I don't want to save these images on the server.

Any idea or suggestion?

Sorry, my english is not too good.

Thanks.

Comment: Im lost in your question. I dont even understand what is your client like(browser, wpf ....)?

Comment: ihttphandler is a good solution in your case. what's the problem with ihttphandler?

Comment: Just have ordinary `<img>` tag with `src` pointing to handler on your server - client will have to allow external images, there's no real way to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing this, you would need to do something like:

(In your .ashx file)

```
 Response.ContentType = "image/png";
 Response.BinaryWrite( <bytes> );
```

Comment: I use a custom pop3/imap client. I want to display a received email from a pop3/imap server. I know the htmlbody and embedded images (content-type, name, content-id, base64string or byte[] as content)

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to show the email in a browser. For that you would need to use an ashx file for returning the images. You would need to setup a RegEx which would look for all the image tags and replace them with calls to the ashx file you've created.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of what your HTML looks like?

Comment: I want to show an email in browser, in a gridview selectindexchanged event. In this event, I try use ihttphandler(ashx), but it not working. In the seletedindexchanged event, I set the div innerhtml with the htmlbody, which is already contains ashx instead of cid:content-id.

Comment: What is happening when you set the div innerHTML ? Does the email html contain an <html> tag ?

Comment: The email html not contain the<html> tag

Comment: What do you mean by "not working". What happens and what doesn't happen when you set the content of the div ?

Comment: In the selectindexchanged event I set div innerhtml, this html alredy contains the replaced img src with ashx. Everything shows correctly expects images. I check the page source, and its fine. The ihttphandler not run after I set the div innerhtml. How sould I force to run?

Comment: You could write some jquery to force the images to load. Something like $('img').refresh(); ?